# Minimum base to count to a string

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

#### The Challenge

**Input:** alphanumeric string. You can assume that the string will only contain the characters [0-9A-Z]. This can come from a parameter, command line, or STDIN. Digits are always before letters in terms of the base. Think like an extended version of HEX.

**Output** `X,Y` Such that `Y` is the *minimum* base required to parse the string and `X` is the decimal value of the input string in that base.

**Examples**

> Input: "1"
>
> Output: 1,2

> Input: "HELLOWORLD"
>
> Output: 809608041709942,33

**Scoring:** This is a golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Borderline dupe of [Base X to base Y conversion](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/write-a-base-x-to-base-y-function?s=7|2.4730). (And probably one or more of the other [370 existing questions](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=base+is%3Aquestion) which talk about bases).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I would argue that this is different from the Base X to Y conversion, primarily because you are not supplied with the start base. It is an additional calculation the program must make. As for the search link, that is why this is specifically tagged as base-conversion.

Comment: I said it was borderline dupe, not identical (although it does only take 5 or 6 chars in golfing languages to extract the base, so it's not exactly a non-trivial difference), and held back from casting a supervote to see whether others agreed. Since no-one else has cast a close vote yet, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40416/21348 (should it be tagged `base-conversion`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, 23 bytes

```
Jmx+jkUTGdrz2KheSJ,iJKK
```

Try it online: [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Jmx%2BjkUTGdrz2KheSJ%2CiJKK&input=HALLOWORLD&debug=0)

```
      UT       create the list [0, 1, 2, ..., 9]
    jk         join them, creates the string "0123456789"
   +    G      G is initialized with the alphabet, add both strings
               creates "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 m        rz2  maps each charater d of input().lower() to: 
  x      d         the index of d in "012...xyz"
J              store the resulting list of indices in J

   SJ          sorted(J) (doesn't sort J in place, but gives you a sorted copy)
  e            last element (=maximum)
 h             + 1
K              store result in K

 iJK           convert J from base K to base 10
,   K          create the tuple (iJK, K) and prints
```

## Pyth, 16 bytes (?)

I'm not sure if this counts. The functionality I'm using was in Pyth for quite a while, but didn't work because of one stupid little bug. So the following code didn't work when the question was asked, although the docs said that it does.

```
DeGJ1#~J1#R,iGJJ
```

This defines a function `e`. Try it [online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=DeGJ1%23~J1%23R%2CiGJJ%3Be%22HALLOWORLD%22e%221%22&debug=0).

This one was based a submission by @Reticality. He uses a different algorithm now though.

```
DeG               Define a function e(G):
   J1               J = 1
     #              while True:
      ~J1             J += 1
         #            try:
            izJ         convert z (=input) from base J into base 10
          R,izJJ        return tuple(base_10, J)
                      if exception (converting failed) do nothing
```

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>74</s> <s>64</s> <s>56</s> <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```py
def f(x):a=ord(max(x))-54;a+=7*(a<8);print int(x,a),a
```

Call the function (i.e. `f("HELLOWORLD")`) and outputs to stdout (`809608041709942 33`)

This is case-sensitive, requiring upper case letters, and crashes for invalid input (e.g. `"$^$%!(&£%)()`)

This code gets the `max` letter in the string (z>x>y>...>b>a>9>8>...>2>1>0) and gets the largest base needed to represent it.

Change the `54` into a `76` to make it work for lowercase (but no longer upper case).

Comment: Does Python not have a `++` operator? That'd save you 2 bytes

Comment: @ColeJohnson It does not.

Comment: You can shorten `if a<8:a+=7` to `a+=7*(a<8)`.

Comment: Would `a+=7*(8>a=ord(max(x))-54);` work? It does in PHP.

Answer (score 6):

## APL (24)

```
{(B⊥D-1),B←⌈/D←⍵⍳⍨⎕D,⎕A}
```

This is a function that takes a string and returns two values, the value and the base.

```
      {(B⊥D-1),B←⌈/D←⍵⍳⍨⎕D,⎕A} 'DEADBEEF'
3735928559 16
```

Explanation:

- `⎕D,⎕A`: digits followed by letters
- `D←⍵⍳⍨`: store in `D` the 1-based index of each character of ⍵ in the string of digits followed by letters
- `B←⌈/D`: store in `B` the highest value in `D`. (which is the base to use)
- `(B⊥D-1)`: subtract 1 from each value in `D` (making them the values of the digits), and decode them as a base-`B` number.

Comment: The question specified bytes but it looks like you've counted characters.

Comment: The APL character set fits in a byte with room to spare. [Here's IBM's standard](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_globalization_pdf_cp00907z.pdf). They don't have to be Unicode bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## Pure Bash, 48

```
for((b=37;$[--b]#$1;)){ :;}
echo $[$[++b]#$1],$b
```

#### Output

```
$ ./minbase.sh HELLOWORLD
./minbase.sh: line 1: ((: 32#HELLOWORLD: value too great for base (error token is "32#HELLOWORLD")
809608041709942,33
$ ./minbase.sh HELLOWORLD 2>/dev/null
809608041709942,33
$ ./minbase.sh 1 2>/dev/null
1,2
$
```

I'm taking advantage of [this meta answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/11259) - specifically that warnings output to STDERR may be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

## J - 50 char

Worry not, Martin, I have come to restore order.

```
(>./@i.(u:(47+i.11),65+i.26&)(,&.":,[)'b',tolower)
```

The `u:(47+i.11),65+i.26` portion creates the string `/0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, and we want the slash so that when we find the largest digit of `HELLOWORLD` with `>./@i.`, we  correct an off-by-one error at no extra charge.

Then we use J's built-in base conversion by evaling e.g. `33bhelloworld`; J has this weird internal language for specifying numbers, so we exploit that to do the base interpretation for us.

```
   (>./@i.(u:(47+i.11),65+i.26&)(,&.":,[)'b',tolower) 'HELLOWORLD'
809608041709942 33
   f =: (>./@i.(u:(47+i.11),65+i.26&)(,&.":,[)'b',tolower)
   f '1'
1 2
   f 'POTATO'
627732894 30
   f '1FISH2FISH'
22338345482731 29
```

Answer (score 4):

## J, 31 bytes

```
3&u:(-47+7*60<]@)(>./(#.,[)<:@)
```

Usage:

```
   f=.3&u:(-47+7*60<]@)(>./(#.,[)<:@)

   f 'POTATO'
627732894 30
   f '1FISH2FISH'
22338345482731 29
```

1 byte thanks to @FUZxxl.

[Try it online here.](http://tryj.tk/)

Comment: Use `u:` instead of `a.&i.` I guess.

Comment: @FUZxxl Right, `3&u:` works. (The self-written adverbs got my full attention. I just understood them properly and they are quite useful for golfing.)

Answer (score 3):

### CJam (25 chars)

```
q{i48-_9>7*-}%_:e>):Zb',Z
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7Bi48-_9%3E7*-%7D%25_%3Ae%3E)%3AZb'%2CZ%0A&input=HELLOWORLD)

It's 28 chars in GolfScript, mainly because `base` doesn't have a one-char alias:

```
{48-.9>7*-}%.$-1=):^base','^
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 55 bytes

<s>Hmmm, beating J with Mathematica? Something's fishy...</s>

```
Print[f=FromDigits;f[#,y=f/@Max@Characters@#+1],",",y]&
```

This defines an unnamed function, which takes the string as a parameter and prints the result. You can either give it a name or use it directly:

```
Print[f=FromDigits;f[#,y=f/@Max@Characters@#+1],",",y]&@"HELLOWORLD"
```

The idea is pretty simple. Mathematica's integer parser supports bases up to 36 out of the box, so we only need to figure out the minimum base. We do that with

```
y=f/@Max@Characters@#+1
```

where `#` is the function's parameter and we've defined `f` as an alias of `FromDigits`. Note that `FromDigits` normally reads things in base 10, but that doesn't change the value of a single digit. Then we just use that to parse the string with `f[#,y...]` and the print the result, a comma and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>100</s> 89 bytes

Thanks to nderscore for saving 10 bytes!

Works for base-2 to base-36; that's all bases JavaScript's `parseInt` supports.

```js
function b(s){for(i=1;(x=parseInt(s,++i))!=x|!x.toString(i)[s.length-1];);return x+","+i}
```

The code uses a for loop starting from 1 and tries to parse the int on base-N (I use N here as `i + 1`; `i` is incremented before parsing the number) is the current number in the loop. It checks whether the parsed int is not NaN (`x==x` is the shortest way, and it works because `NaN != NaN`). It also checks that the integer converted to base-N equals the original string; this is necessary because when JavaScript parses an int, only the first part has to be valid, so `parseInt` would be able to parse "abc" on base-11 because "a" is a valid base-11 integer (while "b" and "c" are not). If the input cannot be parsed in base-N, then the for loop continues until it finds the correct base; after the for loop, the function returns the base-10 number and the original base.

Ungolfed code:

```js
function getBase(str) {
    for (var base = 1;
    (parsed = parseInt(s, ++base)) != parsed | !parsed.toString(base)[str.length - 1];);
    return parsed + "," + base;
}
```

Comment: -10 bytes: `function b(s){for(i=1;(x=parseInt(s,++i))!=x||!x.toString(i)[s.length-1];);return x+","+i}`

Comment: @nderscore Nice, thanks! Now I could actually get -11 bytes, because the `||` operator can be shortened to the bitwise `|` operator, which still gives the same results here.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust (1.0 beta), <del>81</del> 80 bytes

```
let f=|a|loop{for i in 2..{if let Ok(m)=u64::from_str_radix(a,i){return(m,i)}}};
```

Test:

```
fn main() {
    let f=|a|loop{for i in 2..{if let Ok(m)=u64::from_str_radix(a,i){return(m,i)}}};
    assert_eq!(f("1"), (1, 2));
    assert_eq!(f("POTATO"), (627732894, 30));
    assert_eq!(f("HELLOWORLD"), (809608041709942, 33));
    println!("ok!");
}
```

---

This is similar to all other answers, we try to parse the string into an integer using the internal function `u32::from_str_radix`, and start from base 2 and return immediately.

Rust is static-typed, and it requires all reachable branches to return the same type of value. The `for` loop is *not* infinite, so Rust would require a return value after the `for` loop. In order to make the type-checker happer, an outer infinite `loop` is added to make sure there is no other exit point. This saves 1 byte compared with returning a default value.

Answer (score 1):

## J (61)

Explicit funcions in J can be... Somewhat hard to read.

```
3 :'(+/i*b^|.x:i.#y),b=.>:>./i=.(y i.~a.{~(48+i.10),65+i.26)'
```

#### Example usage:

```
   f=: 3 :'(+/i*b^|.x:i.#y),b=.>:>./i=.(y i.~a.{~(48+i.10),65+i.26)'
   f 'POTATO'
627732894 30
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 70 <s>72</s>

The base is 1 more than the biggest digit in the string, so sort and find it.

**Edit** Save 2 bytes thx @nderscore (particularly, shame on me for using `>=` instead of `>`)

```js
F=s=>(b=[...s].sort().pop().charCodeAt()-47,[parseInt(s,b-=b>8&&7),b])
// TEST:
C.innerHTML=F('1') + '\n' + F('HELLOWORLD')+ '\n' + F('POTATO')
```

```html
<pre id=C></pre>
```

Comment: -2: `F=s=>(b=[...s].sort().pop().charCodeAt()-47,[parseInt(s,b-=b>8&&7),b])`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 74 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 9.25 bytes

```
⇩:fGkrḟ›…β,
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyLhuaA9IiwiIiwi4oepOmZHa3LhuJ/igLrigKbOsiwiLCIiLCJIRUxMT1dPUkxEIl0=)

Comment: [Doesn't pass the test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oepZkdrcuG4n+KAps6yLCIsIiIsIkhFTExPV09STEQiXQ==) - looks like Vyxal's base conversion function doesn't work.

Comment: @MTN fixed it, i forgot to dupe the string/increment and remove a space i added

Comment: [8.375 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJvPSIsIiIsIuKHqTpmR2ty4bif4oC64oCmzrIiLCIiLCJIRUxMT1dPUkxEIl0=)

Comment: man i was looking for the force output flag....

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 105

Not very short and can probably be improved

```
func n(x:String) {var m=64;for c in x.utf8{m=max(Int(c),m)};println("\(strtoul(x,nil,10+m-64)),\(m-54)")}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 97 bytes

```
import Data.Char
j x|x>64=x-54|1<2=x-47
l=j.ord
m=l.maximum
f x=(foldl(\a b->a*m x+l b-1)0 x,m x)
```

Example run:

```
*Main> map f ["HELLOWORLD", "POTATO", "1"]
[(809608041709942,33),(627732894,30),(1,2)]
```

It's so long because I need do `import Data.Char` for `ord` and I don't have a built in read function for integers of arbitrary base.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP (>=5.4), 90

(-2 for an anoynomous function in PHP 7; 74 for a snippet)

```
function f($s){$b+=7*(8>$b=ord(max(str_split($s)))-54);return[base_convert($s,$b,10),$b];}
```

Thanks @user34736 for the -54(+8) idea; saved two bytes on my -54/-47 approach.

The function returns an array instead of printing the result.
+/-0 for printing:

```
function f($s){$b+=7*(8>$b=ord(max(str_split($s)))-54);echo base_convert($s,$b,10),",$b";}
```

but a return value is easier to test:

```
function test($x,$y,$e){static $h='<table border=1><tr><th>input</th><th>output</th><th>expected</th><th>ok?</th></tr>';echo"$h<tr><td>$x</td><td>$y</td><td>$e</td><td>",(strcmp($y,$e)?'N':'Y'),"</td></tr>";$h='';}
foreach([1=>'1,2','HELLOWORLD'=>'809608041709942,33','ILOVECODEGOLF'=>'21537319965321352644,32','POTATO'=>'627732894,30','1FISH2FISH'=>'22338345482731,29']as$x=>$e)test($x,implode(',',f($x)),$e);echo'</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 217 B

Extended Pascal (as specified by ISO standard 10206) allows you to write (in your source code) `integer` literals up to base 36 (for example `−16#fF` denotes the value `−255` decimal).
To be functionally consistent, all number literals that are allowed *in Pascal source code* are allowed as user input, too:
Therefore the built‑in procedures `read`/`readLn`/`readStr` accept strings constituting valid number literals in your Pascal source (and in fact all numeric representations defined by ISO standard 6093).
The task can be boiled down to determining the minimal base:

```pascal
program p(input,output);var U,P:string(65);Y,X:integer;begin read(U);Y:=2;for X:=1 to length(U)do
Y:=card([1..Y,1..index('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',U[X])]);writeStr(P,Y:1,'#',U);readStr(P,X);write(X,Y)end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program minimumBaseToCountToAString(input, output);
    const
        { Pascal does not make any assertion with regard to character encoding
          (except that `'A' < 'Z'`/`'a' < 'z'` (subject to availability) and
          digit characters `'0'` through `'9'` are consecutive and ascending).
          Hence another mechanism needs to be sought. }
        digit = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    type
        { A `type` range restriction will cause an error
          should we attempt to assign values outside of this range. }
        base = 2‥36;
    var
        unprocessed: string(62);
        { This size is sufficient for `'2#1010…0101'` on a 64‑bit system.
          However, it will not prevent `'36#ZZZ…ZZZ'` overflow mistakes. }
        prefixed: string(65);
        { Stores the value of the largest digit found + 1 (a. k. a. base). } 
        minimumBase: base value 2;
        { Cannot reuse variable since `minimumBase` needs to be printed, too. }
        number: integer;
    begin
        { Reads up to `unprocessed.capacity` characters from `input`
          and discards the remainder of the line. }
        readLn(unprocessed);
        { In Pascal `string` indices are `1`-based. }
        for number ≔ 1 to length(unprocessed) do
        begin
            { Determines the maximum of two values without calculating
              the potential new maximum multiple times.
              The Extended Pascal function `index` returns `0`
              if `representation[number]` is not found in `digit`. }
            minimumBase ≔ card([1‥minimumBase,
                                1‥index(digit, unprocessed[number])]);
        end;
        { The `:1` is necessary so the base specification does not get padded
          with an implementation-defined default number of space characters
          (possibly causing /trailing/ characters to spill over). }
        writeStr(prefixed, minimumBase:1, '#', unprocessed);
        { This performs the actual conversion honoring `minimumBase`. }
        readStr(prefixed, number);
        { I can count to potato! }
        writeLn(number, minimumBase);
    end.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 46 bytes

```ruby
x=0
1until(x=Integer($_,$.+=1)rescue p)
p x,$.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6eUuyCpaUlaboWN_UqbA24DEvzSjJzNCpsPfNKUtNTizRU4nVU9LRtDTWLUouTS1MVCjS5ChQqgGIQXVDNC1Z5uPr4-If7B_m4QEQA)