# Read numbers in the base of the largest digit and write it using underscores

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion

This isn't as much a "challenge" as "a unique problem that there are no built-in functions to solve." Basically, you need to do this:

- Read some lines of numbers from `stdin`. These lines may contain trailing or preceding whitespace, and there may be empty lines. No lines will contain "just whitespace" other than a newline. Each non-empty line will have exactly one number. This:

  ```
   123

  456\t
  ```

  (where `\t` is a tab) is considered valid input.
- Read the numbers in the input in base `N+1`, where `N` is the largest digit in any of the lines. In this case, the largest digit is `6`, so the numbers would be read in base `7`, resulting in 66<sub>10</sub> and 237<sub>10</sub>.
- Find the sum of the numbers. The sum of 66<sub>10</sub> and 237<sub>10</sub> is 303<sub>10</sub>.
- Convert the sum back to base `N+1` again. We'd convert 303<sub>10</sub> to base `7`, which would be 612<sub>7</sub>.
- For each digit, print that many underscores, followed by a space. The last digit should instead be followed by a newline *or* a space and a newline. In our example, that would be `______ _ __\n` or `______ _ __ \n`, where `\n` is the newline character.

Here's an example in Python:

```
import sys

def convert_to_base(n, b):
    'Convert `n` to base `b`'
    res = []
    while n:
        res.append(n % b)
        n /= b
    return res[::-1]

# read the lines, discarding empty ones and stripping any whitespace
lines = map(str.strip, filter(None, list(sys.stdin)))
# find the largest digit, and add 1 to it to make our base
base = max(map(max, (map(int, line) for line in lines)))+1
# read the lines in the base and sum them
result = sum(int(line, base) for line in lines)
# print the result in the original base using underscores, separated by spaces
for number in convert_to_base(result, base):
    print '_'*number,
# print a newline
print
```

This is code golf: the shortest program wins!

Comment: Can you add <sub>7</sub> and <sub>10</sub> to your instructions? - nevermind - i just did that.

Comment: @NotthatCharles What do you mean?

Comment: I was unclear about which base numbers were in.  I edited your question to make them explicit (pending review)

Comment: @NotthatCharles Ah! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pyth, 24 bytes

Just found this question via Twitter.

Notice that quite large parts of the program are similar to isaacg's solution (like base-conversion and the printing part), but the main algorithm is completely different.

```
.V0#jd*R\_jsiRbcjd.z)b.q
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.V0%23jd*R%5C_jsiRbcjd.z)b.q&input=%20123%0A%0A456%09&debug=0)

My solution is based on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48989/29577), I gave to a similar question two months ago.

#### Explanation:

```
.V0                       for b in [0, 1, 2, ...):
   #__________________.q    try-catch block. If ___ is successful, exit the program (.q), 
                            otherwise do nothing
               cjd.z)         read all input (.z), join lines by spaces (jd) and split (c))
                              this gives a list of numbers (but still in string format)
            iRb               convert each number from base b
           s                  sum, add all numbers up
          j          b        convert to base b
      *R\_                    multiply each digit with "_"
    jd                        join with spaces
                              implicit print
```

The infinite loop `.V0` combined with the try-catch `#___.q` basically finds the first number `b >= 0`, with which the conversion `iRb` doesn't throw an error. And this happens, when `b` is equal to the largest digit + 1.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 26

```
JscR).zjd*R\_jsiRKhseSsJJK
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JscR).zjd*R%5C_jsiRKhseSsJJK&input=123%20%0A%0A%20456%20%20%20&debug=0)

```
JscR).z
     .z                       Take the input as a list of lines.
  cR)                         Remove all whitespace from each line.
 s                            Combine the lines.
J                             Save the result to J.
                              J is now the list of the string forms of the numbers.
       jd*R\_jsiRKhseSsJJK
                      sJ      Combine J into one string.
                    eS        Find the maximum of that string.
                   s          Convert it to an integer.
                  h           Add one.
                 K            Save to K. K is the base.
               iRK      J     Convert the strings in J to base K.
              s               Add them together.
             j           K    Convert the result back to base K, as a list of ints.
         *R\_                 Map each int in that list to that many underscores.
       jd                     Join on spaces and print.
```

Comment: Your Pyth answers always manage to surprise me!

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
q_$W=~)_@N%::~fb:+\b'_f*S*N
```

*UPDATE - 1 byte saved thanks to Martin*

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%25%3A%3A~_e_%24W%3D)%3AXfb%3A%2BXb'_f*S*N&input=%20123%0A%0A456%20%0A%0A%0A)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>188</s> 182

```
function f($s){$b=max(str_split($s))+1;foreach(preg_split('/\s/',$s)as$x)$m+=base_convert($x,$b,10);foreach(str_split(base_convert($m,10,$b))as$d)echo' ',str_repeat('_',$d);echo'
```

';}

prints a leading blank instead of a trailing one. if not accepted, add +1.

breakdown:

```
function f($s)
{
    $b=max(str_split($s))+1;           // find base
    foreach(preg_split('/\s/',$s)as$x) // extract all words and loop
        $m+=base_convert($x,$b,10);    // convert, sum up
    foreach(str_split(base_convert($m,10,$b))as$d) // convert back, split into array, loop
        echo' ',str_repeat('_',$d);    // print underscores
    echo'
';                                     // append newline
}
```

I wonder if there is a golfier approach to this ...