# What base is this number in?

Tags: code-golf, math, base-conversion

Here's a nice easy challenge:

> Given a string that represents a number in an unknown base, determine the lowest possible base that number might be in. The string will only contain `0-9, a-z`. If you like, you may choose to take uppercase letters instead of lowercase, but please specify this. You must output this lowest possible base in decimal.

Here is a more concrete example. If the input string was "01234", it is impossible for this number to be in binary, since 2, 3, and 4 are all undefined in binary. Similarly, this number cannot be in base 3, or base 4. Therefore, this number *must* be in base-5, or a higher base, so you should output '5'.

Your code must work for any base between base 1 (unary, all '0's) and base 36 ('0-9' and 'a-z').

You may take input and provide output in any reasonable format. Base-conversion builtins are allowed. As usual, standard loopholes apply, and the shortest answer in bytes is the winner!

## Test IO:

```
#Input          #Output
00000       --> 1
123456      --> 7
ff          --> 16
4815162342  --> 9
42          --> 5
codegolf    --> 25
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz    --> 36
```

Comment: my language doesn't really support string input, may I accept input as ascii integers separated by newlines?

Comment: I know it seems a bit "unreasonable" so I doubt its ok

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala, what's your language?

Comment: S.I.L.O.S https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S @Dopapp

Comment: In Python 3, could I take input as a byte string?

Comment: Can I output in base 36?

Comment: @LeakyNun Geez, I hope not.

Comment: @LeakyNun `You must output this lowest possible base in decimal.`

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala If that's your languages closest equivalent to a string, I don't see why not.

Comment: @Peter, I was just looking for dupes, but I think http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48952/8478 is a better fit?

Comment: Although this is only a subset of [the earlier question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51239/194), it's a subset which is easy to extract.

Comment: @MartinEnder, you're right. Do you need me to retract my close vote, or are your powers sufficient without?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I can undo it myself, don't worry. (Although I do think the new spec is better than the old...)

Comment: Wait actually, I'm not sure it's a dupe of either. This only asks for the base, not for the actual conversion... I'll reopen this and let the community decide, but I don't think we'd close a prime-testing challenge as a dupe of any other challenge requiring a primality test either.

Comment: Usually unary is all 1s, and leading zeros are not standard for any positional-based numeric system.

Comment: Well, you lost me after the fourth test input.

Comment: if for hex the Greater digit is F, than yes for 36 is Z

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṀØBi
```

Requires uppercase. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmAw5hCaQ&input=&args=J0NPREVHT0xGJw) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmAw5hCaQrDh-KCrEc&input=&args=JzAwMDAwJywgJzEyMzQ1NicsICdGRicsICc0ODE1MTYyMzQyJywgJzQyJywgJ0NPREVHT0xGJywgJzAxMjM0NTY3ODlBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWic).

#### How it works

```
ṀØBi  Main link. Arguments: s (string)

Ṁ     Yield the maximum of s.
 ØB   Yield "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".
   i  Find the 1-based index of the maximum in that string.
```

Comment: It's actually 7 bytes, not 4. The first 2 chars are multi-byte.

Comment: @Nicomak This answer is encoded in the [Jelly code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), where all of these characters are encoded as 1 byte each.

Answer (score 27):

## Python, <s>27</s> 22 bytes

```python
lambda s:(max(s)-8)%39
```

This requires the input to be a bytestring (Python 3) or a bytearray (Python 2 and 3).

*Thanks to @AleksiTorhamo for golfing off 5 bytes!*

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/YXmMBD).

#### How it works

We begin by taking the maximum of the string. This the code points of letters are higher than the code points of digits, this maximal character is also the maximal base 36 digit.

The code point of **'0' – '9'** are **48 – 57**, so we must subtract **48** from their code points to compute the corresponding digits, or **47** to compute the lowest possible base. Similarly, the code points of the letters **'a' – 'z'** are **97 – 122**. Since **'a'** represents the digit with value **10**, we must subtract **87** from their code points to compute the corresponding digits, or **86** to compute the lowest possible base. One way to achieve this is as follows.

The difference between **97** and **58** (**':'**, the character after **'9'**) is **39**, so taking the code points modulo **39** can achieve the subtraction. Since **48 % 39 = 9**, and the desired result for the character **'0'** is **1**, we first subtract **8** before taking the result modulo **39**. Subtracting first is necessary since otherwise **'u' % 39 = 117 % 39 = 0**.

```python
c    n    n-8    (n-8)%39
0    48    40     1
1    49    41     2
2    50    42     3
3    51    43     4
4    52    44     5
5    53    45     6
6    54    46     7
7    55    47     8
8    56    48     9
9    57    49    10
a    97    89    11
b    98    90    12
c    99    91    13
d   100    92    14
e   101    93    15
f   102    94    16
g   103    95    17
h   104    96    18
i   105    97    19
j   106    98    20
k   107    99    21
l   108   100    22
m   109   101    23
n   110   102    24
o   111   103    25
p   112   104    26
q   113   105    27
r   114   106    28
s   115   107    29
t   116   108    30
u   117   109    31
v   118   110    32
w   119   111    33
x   120   112    34
y   121   113    35
z   122   114    36
```

Comment: If you make it Python 3, and take the input as a byte string, you can drop the `ord()` and win by 3 bytes. :)

Comment: Nice idea! Let me ask the OP.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo NOOOOOOOOOOOO y u do dis

Answer (score 22):

## Python, 25 bytes

```
lambda x:int(max(x),36)+1
```

Defines a lambda that takes the string `x`. Finds the largest digit in the string (sorted with letters above digits, by python's default), and converts to base 36. Adds 1, because `8` is not in base 8.

Answer (score 11):

### Haskell, 34 bytes

```haskell
f s=length['\t'..maximum s]`mod`39
```

Uses the `mod(ord(c)-8,39)` idea from Dennis.

**41 bytes**

```haskell
g '0'=1
g 'W'=1
g x=1+g(pred x)
g.maximum
```

---

**45 bytes:**

```haskell
(`elemIndex`(['/'..'9']++['a'..'z'])).maximum
```

Outputs like `Just 3`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), <s>34</s> <s>29</s> 21 bytes

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to Dennis!!!*

```
s->(s.bytes.max-8)%39
```

Uses lowercase letters

[Try it online](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=cy0-KHMuYnl0ZXMubWF4LTgpJTM5&input=JzBmZic)

### Explanation

```
s -> (      // Input is `s`
  s.bytes    // Returns array of char codes
   .max      // Get maximum item in array
) % 39      // Modulus 39
```

Comment: Or you could just [put quotes around the input](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=QC5ieXRlcy5tYXAobi0-bj42MD9uLTU0Om4tNDcpLm1heA&input=JzM0Jw&debug=on)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem .___. i didn't even know my own language could do that

Comment: How about `(-)&8` instead of `n->n-8`?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien >_>_>_> I haven't gotten to that yet. I was _just_ planning to do it and then this challenge was posted. Bassically `f&n` bonds `n` to first arg of the function.

Comment: @Downgoat Oh. >_>

Comment: Then how about `(+)&-8`? Nevermind, that doesn't save any bytes...

Comment: `s->(s.bytes.max-8)%39` saves 8 though, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Dennis yes it does... >_> I'm not sure how I missed that

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/), 6 bytes

```
{¤36ö>
```

Takes letters in upper case.

**Explanation**

```
{       # sort
 ¤      # take last
  36ö   # convert from base 36 to base 10
     >  # increment
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=e8KkMzbDtj4&input=Q09ERUdPTEY)

Comment: Forgive my naivete with 05AB1E, but do you mean convert FROM base 36 (to base 10)?

Comment: @Keeta You are of course correct. My bad.

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, 22 bytes

```julia
!s=(maximum(s)-'')%39
```

There's a BS character (0x08) between the quotes. [Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IXM9KG1heGltdW0ocyktJwgnKSUzOQpwcmludCghIjEyMyIp&input=)

Comment: what does the `-''` do?

Comment: It subtracts 8 from the code point and returns an integer.

Answer (score 5):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 6 bytes

```
M6²@¿u
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=TTbCskDCv3U&input=J0NPREVHT0xGJw)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>41</s> 37 bytes

```
s=>parseInt([...s].sort().pop(),36)+1
```

Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to @edc65.

Comment: use `pop()` to save 4

Comment: @edc65 I can't believe that's not under JavaScript tips.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>55</s> 40 bytes

```
f=(\y->mod(y-8)39).Data.Char.ord.maximum
```

Thanks @Dennis for his approach. (take that, @xnor ;))

Comment: I think you can remove `f=` for 38 bytes since `f` doesn't take explicit arguments.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 6: 18 bytes

```
{:36(.comb.max)+1}
```

Defines a lambda that takes a single string argument, and returns an integer. It splits the string into characters, finds the "highest" one, converts it to base 36, adds 1.

```
{(.ords.max-8)%39}
```

This one uses the modulo approach from Dennis. Same length.

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 28 bytes

```
O`.
.\B

{2`
$`
}T01`dl`_o
.
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApPYC4KLlxCCgp7MmAKJGAKfVQwMWBkbGBfbwou&input=MDAwMDAKMTIzNDU2CmZmCjQ4MTUxNjIzNDIKNDIKY29kZWdvbGYKMDEyMzQ1Njc4OWFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

#### Explanation

```
O`.
```

This sorts the characters of the input.

```
.\B
```

This removes all characters except the last, so the first two stages find the maximum character.

```
{2`
$`
}T01`dl`_o
```

These are two stages which form a loop. The first one duplicates the first character and the second one "decrements" it (replacing e.g. `x` with `w`, `a` with `9` and `1` with `0`). The latter stage encounters a zero as the first character, it removes it instead. This is a standard technique for generating a range of characters, given the upper end. Hence, this generates all "digits" from `0` to the maximum digit.

```
.
```

Finally, we simply count the number of digits, which gives us the base.

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>99</s> <s>89</s> 85 bytes

Look ! Less than 100 bytes !
Look ! *10* bytes off !
Look ! *4* bytes off !

```
ifelse((m=max(strsplit(scan(,''),"")[[1]]))%in%(l=letters),match(m,l)+10,strtoi(m)+1)
```

**Ungolfed :**

```
l=letters                  #R's built-in vector of lowercase letters

n=scan(what=characters())  #Takes an input from STDIN and convert it to characters

m=max(strsplit(n,"")[[1]]) #Splits the input and takes to max. 
                           #`letters` are considered > to numbers (i.e. a>1)


ifelse(m%in%l,match(m,l)+10,strtoi(m)+1) #If the max is in `letters`,
                                             #outputs the matching position of `m`in `letters` + 10 (because of [0-9]). 
                                             #Else, outputs `m` (as a number) + 1.
```

As often, this answer makes use of the `ifelse` function : `ifelse(Condition, WhatToDoIfTrue, WhatToDoElse)`

Comment: I love your version; however, treating letters and numbers separately creates those pesky extra bytes. Please have a look at my solution that uses a different method.

Comment: Your answer is interesting indeed. I will use the your `scan` method to golf some bytes ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 25 bytes

`print((args(0).max-8)%39)`

Run it like:

`$ scala whatbase.scala 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>34</s> 32 bytes

*saved 2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender*

```
Max@BaseForm[Characters@#,36]+1&
```

Defines a pure function that takes a string as input.

Splits the input into characters, converts them to base 36 numbers, and returns the maximum +1.

Comment: `Max@BaseForm[Characters@#,36]+1&`

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>34</s> 32 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to Martin Ender*

```
Max@Mod[ToCharacterCode@#-8,39]&
```

I decided the different method deserved a new answer.

<sub>method <s>stolen</s> inspired by Dennis' solution</sub>

Comment: Use some prefix notation: `Max@Mod[ToCharacterCode@#-8,39]&` (same goes for your other answer)

Comment: Also, you need to add `&` to the end to indicate an anonymous function.

Comment: You forgot one `@` in both of your answers (`ToCharacterCode@#` and `Characters@#`).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>51</s> 38 bytes

(From Dennis) ^^

```
<?=(ord(max(str_split($argv[1])))-8)%39;
```

Other proposal without Dennis' trick

```
<?=($a=max(str_split($argv[1])))<a?$a+1:ord($a)-86;
```

- Takes input as argument $argv[1];
- Take max character (using ASCII) values
- If it is a number (inferior to < 'a' ascii value) then output number+1
- Else output ascii value -86 (97 for 'a' in ascii, -11 for 'a' is 11th base-digit)

Comment: It's too bad PHP has such verbose function names: `<?=base_convert(max(str_split($argv[1])),36,10)+1` is an elegant solution, but at 49 bytes!

Comment: @YiminRong you can use `intval()` instead of `base_convert()` which shortens down to 38 bytes `<?=intval(max(str_split($argn)),36)+1;` tio: https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42M6@kLDFHIzexQqO4pCi@uCAns0RDJbEoPU9TU8fYTFPb0Pr//@T8lNT0/Jy0f/kFJZn5ecX/dd0A

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 20 bytes

```
@(a)mod(max(a)-8,39)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 6 bytes

```
Seb36h
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=Seb36h&input=%22123456f%22&warnings=0)

```
Se     -   sorted(input)[-1]
  b36  -  base(^, 36)
     h - ^ + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>67</s> 61 bytes

```
int c(char[]i){int m=0;for(int c:i)m=m>c?m:c;return(m-8)%39;}
```

`(m-8)%39` is thanks to [*@Dennis*' amazing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90719/52210).

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/6m93TS)

```
class Main{
  static int c(char[] i){
    int m = 0;
    for(int c : i){
      m = m > c
           ? m
           : c;
    }
    return (m-8) % 39;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("00000".toCharArray()));
    System.out.println(c("123456".toCharArray()));
    System.out.println(c("ff".toCharArray()));
    System.out.println(c("4815162342".toCharArray()));
    System.out.println(c("42".toCharArray()));
    System.out.println(c("codegolf".toCharArray()));
    System.out.println(c("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray()));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
7
16
9
5
25
36
```

Comment: Instead of `Math.max()` you can use `m = m>c?m:c`

Comment: @RobAu Ah of course, thanks. Completely forgot about it.. Sometimes I forget the easiest codegolfing things in Java that are even mentioned multiple times in the [Tips for Codegolfing in Java post](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java). Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: If you switch to Java 8 you can replace this whole function with a lambda that does a single `reduce`

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I know, which is why I specifically mentioned it as Java 7. Feel free to post a Java 8 lambda as a separate answer.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I wonder if that would end up with less bytes..

Answer (score 1):

### R, <s>62</s> 54 bytes

```
max(match(strsplit(scan(,''),"")[[1]],c(0:9,letters)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
max(
  match( # 2: Finds the respective positions of these characters
    strsplit(scan(,''),"")[[1]], # 1: Breaks the input into characters
                                c(0:9,letters)) # 3: In the vector "0123...yz"
                                                )
```

Update: shaved off 8 bytes due to the redundancy of `na.rm=T` under the assumption of input validity.

A 39% improvement in size compared to [Frédéric's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90759/49439). Besides that, it runs a wee bit faster: 0.86 seconds for 100000 replications versus 1.09 seconds for the competing answer. So the one of mine is both smaller and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 10 bytes

*Thanks to Martin Ender for saving me a few bytes!*

Uses [Dennis's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90719/53880)

```
q:e>8-i39%
```

[Try it online](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90719/53880)

### CJam, <s>18</s> 16 btyes

Alternative solution:

```
A,s'{,97>+q:e>#)
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=A%2Cs'%7B%2C97%3E%2B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Push%20the%20string%20%220123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20q%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Get%20the%20input%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ae%3E%20%20%20e%23%20Find%20the%20highest%20character%20in%20the%20input%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20%20e%23%20Find%20the%20index%20of%20that%20character%20in%20the%20string%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%20e%23%20Increment&input=543a)

```
A,s'{,97>+       e# Push the string "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
          q      e# Get the input
           :e>   e# Find the highest character in the input
              #  e# Find the index of that character in the string
               ) e# Increment
```

Answer (score 1):

### C89, <s>55</s> <s>53</s> <s>52</s> 50 bytes

```
f(s,b)char*s;{return*s?f(s+1,*s>b?*s:b):(b-8)%39;}
```

*`-8%39` shamelessly stolen from Dennis*

#### Test

```
test(const char* input)
{
    printf("%36s -> %u\n", input, f((char*)input,0));
}

main()
{
    test("00000");
    test("123456");
    test("ff");
    test("4815162342");
    test("42");
    test("codegolf");
    test("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
}
```

#### Output

```
                               00000 -> 1
                              123456 -> 7
                                  ff -> 16
                          4815162342 -> 9
                                  42 -> 5
                            codegolf -> 25
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -> 36
```

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Toby Speight*

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

Comment: You can save 2 bytes with the non-prototype declaration: `f(char*s,int b)` becomes `f(s,b)char*s;`.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by removing the unnecessary parenthesis and space: [`f(s,b)char*s;{return*s?f(s+1,*s>b?*s:b):(b-8)%39;}`](https://ideone.com/mg5Rzb)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thx

Answer (score 1):

## C, 55 bytes

This answer assumes that the input is in ASCII (or identical in the numbers and letters, e.g. ISO-8859 or UTF-8):

```
m;f(char*s){for(m=0;*s;++s)m=m>*s?m:*s;return(m-8)%39;}
```

We simply iterate along the string, remembering the largest value seen, then use the well-known modulo-39 conversion from base-{11..36}.

## Test program

```
int printf(char*,...);
int main(int c,char **v){while(*++v)printf("%s -> ",*v),printf("%d\n",f(*v));}
```

## Test results

```
00000 -> 1
123456 -> 7
ff -> 16
4815162342 -> 9
42 -> 5
codegolf -> 25
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -> 36
```

Comment: Couldn't you remove the m=0? If m appears at the top level of the file, its extern which implies static which implies it is initialized to zero.

Comment: @Batman - yes, but only if you won't call `f()` more than once.  I know that almost anything's fair game in golf, but my professional instincts regard that as too fragile!

Comment: On further thought, I could make it an external requirement to reset `m` between calls to `f()`.  Then my test program could still work.

Comment: @Batman: on [meta], the majority opinion on the question "[Do function submissions have to be reusable?](//meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4939)" seems to be against allowing single-use functions.  So I'll stick with what I have.  Thanks for the suggestion, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

### C# REPL, 17 bytes

```
x=>(x.Max()-8)%39
```

Just ported @Dennis's answer to C#.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
kr$Gḟ›
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kr%24G%E1%B8%9F%E2%80%BA&inputs=codegolf&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>57</s> <s>50</s> 48 bytes

*7 bytes saved thnks to @kamaroso97*
*2 bytes saved thanks to @Neil*

```
n=>Math.max(...[...n].map(a=>parseInt(a,36))+1)
```

Original answer:

```
n=>n.split``.map(a=>parseInt(a,36)).sort((a,b)=>b-a)[0]+1
```

Comment: You can knock off 7 bytes with `n=>Math.max(...n.split``.map(a=>parseInt(a,36)+1))`.

Comment: @kamoroso94 I didn't realize `Math.max` existed. Thanks for telling me about it!

Comment: `[...s]` is shorter than `s.split\`\``.

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 10 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Prompts for uppercase input.

```apl
⌈/⍞⍳⍨⎕D,⎕A
```

`⌈/` maximum

`⍞` characters of input

`⍳⍨` 1-indexed into

`⎕D,` all digits followed by

`⎕A` all characters

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2308/%u2375%u2373%u2368%u2395D%2C%u2395A%7D%A8%2700000%27%20%27123456%27%20%27FF%27%20%274815162342%27%20%2742%27%20%27CODEGOLF%27%20%270123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%27&run)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, <s>30</s> 27 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with the input on STDIN, e.g.

```
base.pl <<< codegolf
```

`base.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
\@F[unpack"W*"];$_=@F%39-9
```

Answer (score 0):

## BASH 70

```
grep -o .|sort -r|head -c1|od -An -tuC|sed s/$/-86/|bc|sed s/-/39-/|bc
```

Input letters are lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

## R, <strike>59</strike> 57 bytes

Thanks to @Andreï-Kostyrka for two bytes.

```
max(which(c(0:9,letters)%in%strsplit(scan(,""),"")[[1]]))
```

`scan(,'')` takes the input and coerces it to a string. Then `strsplit` divides it into its individual characters. `[[1]]` is because that returns a list. `%in%` then checks which of the vector `0,1,2,...,8,9,a,b,c,...,x,y,z` is in the input. which tells us the place in that vector of items in the input -- and `max` finds the biggest place -- which corresponds to the base.

Comment: Try removing the two extra spaces to save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

### Powershell, 62 bytes

```
function t($s){(($s[0..$s.Length]|measure -Max).Maximum-8)%39}
```

%39 @Dennis, of course :)

Comment: Input through a variable isn't one of our [accepted input methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8731/31625), so unless I've misunderstood something, you should revert to using a function or convert this snippet to a full program.

Answer (score 0):

### LiveScript, 32 bytes

```
->1+parseInt (it/'')sort!pop!,36
```

A port of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90745) in my favorite language that compile to JavaScript. If `base~number` operator worked with variables I could write `->1+36~(it/'')sort!pop!` (23 bytes), but it conflicts with the function bind operator :/

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell full program, 56 <strike>62</strike> bytes

lowercase letters required.

```
([int]((read-host).ToCharArray()|sort|select -l 1)-8)%39
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
Hà>
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4/ACu///o5WSlXQUlPJBRAqISAUR6XCxHBCRphQLAA) or [validate all test cases](https://tio.run/##bc5JDoJAEIXhvacgvYYEcEA3sDHGeAXCAhAUJ1ScT@NdPFjrD0kRo5svL13VVVVWcVJk2puMZ4EyLMs3VKCnr6evTR0qW5nGL1EnVA7RhS70oA@DupwT8zrWpSE40uQ0nb8j3PZLE1NiCXPIYCFvm3aNLXP/X/XBk0tGEEMC6ff8XJYsoYAVrGXnFnZyxx4OcIQKTnCGC1zhBnd4qOgN).

Explanation:

```
          # implicit input
H         # convert each digit to decimal
 à        # maximum
  >       # add 1
          # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `G`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
36b⁺
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPVJkJmNvZGU9MzZiJUUyJTgxJUJBJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JTIyMDAwMDAlMjIlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwMSUwQSUyMjEyMzQ1NiUyMiUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMC0lM0UlMjA3JTBBJTIyZmYlMjIlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwMTYlMEElMjI0ODE1MTYyMzQyJTIyJTIwJTIwLSUzRSUyMDklMEElMjI0MiUyMiUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMC0lM0UlMjA1JTBBJTIyY29kZWdvbGYlMjIlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwMjUlMEElMjIwMTIzNDU2Nzg5YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXolMjIlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwMzYmZmxhZ3M9Q0c=)

Takes input in uppercase.

##### Explanation

```python
36b⁺  # Implicit input
36b   # Convert each character from base-36
   ⁺  # Increment each integer
      # Implicit output of maximum
```